# Transfer yii2 application from a local computer to a server

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a finished yii application from my local computer. What I want now is to transfer it to my IBM server, but it seems, a simple "copy-paste" will not work. Can somebody please enumerate the steps to transfer my yii application to my IBM server. And if there is any software my server needs. Thank you!!!

Comment: Why do you think that simple copy-paste will not work?

Comment: It doesn't run properly..

Comment: And what does "doesn't run properly" actually mean? You get some errors?

Comment: Yes. What I need now is the step-by-step on how to transfer yii2 application to my IBM server

Answer (score 0):

Using version control would be recommended.

You can use Git, Subversion or something else.   Push the code up from your computer directly to your server or to your remote repository.

Comment: Of course, I use it everyday!   Here are a few examples of pushing from local to a remote server.  https://medium.com/@francoisromain/vps-deploy-with-git-fea605f1303b.  http://krisjordan.com/essays/setting-up-push-to-deploy-with-git.   Or you could push your repository to Bitbucket or Github and then log into the remote server and pull down the repository that way.